# How to check if textbox contains only zero and display an alert message?

Tags: c#, string, string-matching

I use windows forms with `C#` . I have a form with `button1` and `textbox1`.

What I want is: When I click `button1`, display alert message if the `textbox1` contains any zero or zeros (any combination of zeros only) something like:

```
0
00
0000
000
000000000
```

I tried the following code but it will not work if `textbox1` has more than one zero (like 000)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    if (textBox1.Text == "0")
        MessageBox.Show("Enter Value larger than zero);
}
```

How can I get alert message if `textbox1` has *any combination of zeros* when `button1` is clicked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just trim the 0 char by doing something like this:

```
var text1 = "00000000";
var text2 = "00009000";

Console.WriteLine("Text1: {0}", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text1.Trim('0')));
Console.WriteLine("Text2: {0}", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text2.Trim('0')));
```

Which returns:

> Text1: true
>
> Text2: false //Because we have 9 in the middle of the text.

In your code you will have something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
     if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text.Trim('0'))
           MessageBox.Show("Enter Value larger than zero");
}
```

Comment: @ CodeNotFound . thank you for your help. your code worked well but when I type 0.00 into textbox it gives error ( I want it to give alert message instead). can you help please? thank you

Comment: Trim method receive an array of char you want to trim. If you want to remove '.' character then use Trim like this : `textBox1.Text.Trim('0', '.')`. You can add any char as needed to the Trim method.

Answer (score 6):

You can check if the string contains only zeros (0) like this

```
var str = "000000000";
var isZero = str.All(c => c == '0');
```

Or with `Regex`

```
var isZeroWithRegex = Regex.IsMatch(str, "^0+$");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
if(value ==0)
{
//show
}
else
{
//do something else
}
```

You can convert the value to integer to do so. You may need to add some validations for string checking etc though.

Comment: This is not safe. Because if user type something like `000zed` which is not a number your `Convert.ToInt32` will trhow an exception.

Comment: @ Saransh Kataria . thank you for your help, this code worked well but if the textbox is empty then I get error because of the convert function. can you please help . thank you

Comment: @CodeNotFound I already mentioned that validation/checks for string checking need to be in place for this to work

Comment: @naouf you can use if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text))

Answer (score 2):

From what the question states you want to know if there is any zero in the textbox. the easiest way to do that would be

`if (textBox1.Text.Contains("0"))
        MessageBox.Show("Enter Value larger than zero);`

However if you want to ensure that the value is greater that zero convert it to an int and check.

```
int numberEntered;
if (!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text,out numberEntered)){
   //handle conversion error
}
if (numberEntered == 0)
    MessageBox.Show("Enter Value larger than zero);`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use:

```
int convertedText=Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
if(convertedText==0)
{
...
}
```

Comment: This is not safe. Because if user type something like `000zed` which is not a number your `Convert.ToInt32` will trhow an exception.

Comment: @  CodeNotFound . I allowed the textbox to accept only numbers but the problem is :  if the textbox is empty then I get error because of the convert function. can you please help

Answer (score 1):

To do this do:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
           if ( int.Parse(textBox1.Text) == 0)

            MessageBox.Show("Enter Value larger than zero");
}
```

That will turn the string in to an int, and 00, 000, 0000, etc, is equal to 0.

Comment: This is not safe. Because if user type something like `000bd` which is not a number your `int.parse` will trhow an exception.

Answer (score 1):

I'll explain to my way . First  i am replacing all "0"  an than check length because if this text has "0" more than one length not equals 0 otherwise length must be 0

```
if(textBox1.Text.Replace("0","").Length==0)
```

Comment: This is what Trim method do in a simple syntax.